# Thread safe increment of static local variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, static

```
void foo() {
    static int id = 0;
    const int local_id = id++;
    //do something with local_id;
}
```

Multiple threads can call foo in parallel multiple times. I want each call of foo use "unique" value of local_id. Is it ok with the above code? I wonder if second thread assign the value of id to local_id before the value is increased by the first thread. If it is not safe, is there any standard solution for this?

Comment: use [`std::atomic_int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/atomic)

Comment: Note that the *initialization* of id may or may not be threadsafe depending on whether your compiler supports "magic statics".

Comment: @dlf Right, but it's worth mentioning that "magic statics" are required by C++11, so it's a question of compiler conformance, not of supporting an optional feature.

Comment: @Agnew, true, but the question doesn't call out C++11 :). It's too late to edit, but otherwise I'd revise it to say "whether or not you have a C++11 compiler that supports magic statics".

Comment: Is this really C++11? It seems more like C to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code is not thread-safe, because multiple threads can read `id` concurrently, and producing the same value of `local_id`.

If you want a thread-safe version, use `std::atomic_int`, which is available in C++11:

```
void foo() {
    static std::atomic_int id;
    const int local_id = id++;
    //do something with local_id;
}
```

Comment: Note that if you are using a Microsoft compiler, the initialization of `id` will not be threadsafe since they don't yet support "magic statics" (as of VS2013). In other words, if `foo` has never been called and then two threads both call it at the same time, `id`'s constructor could run twice in parallel with unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not thread safe because two threads may increment id at the same time.

Use [mutual exclusion](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/) or std::atomic for the shared id variable.

Comment: How can mutual exclusion be used in the above case? Can you please elaborate a little bit further?

Comment: Wrap the static inside a class and provide get/increment methods that acquire the mutex before performing the operation.